# Marcadores en mapa 3d

Tags: javascript, 3d

Quiero desarrollar un mapa 3d con canvas tengo esto de momento:
https://codepen.io/Oficialsoulpromotions/pen/gZqLqX
La duda está en que quiero añadir marcadores en el mapa (que se adapten a la localización, que giren con el mapa etc.).
La complicación esta en que no deja de ser una imagen que va girando. Tiene latitud y logitud y la funcion goTo te lleva a las coordenadas de hong kong pero no se si se podrá añadir un marcador que se quede en el mapa. Alguna idea de como hacerlo? 
Gracias.